# How to get a value from Dijit.Editor?

Tags: dojo

I have a dijit.editor on my page and when I click on a button I want the contents inside my editor. It should be fairly simple, but I've stumbled upon it for now.

Never mind, i solved it.

```
   dojo.require("dijit.Editor");

  dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
      var editor = dijit.byId("myEditor");
      var btn1 = dojo.byId("Button1");

      editor.attr("value", "Hej igen"); 
      editor.onLoadDeferred.addCallback(function() {
          editor.atte("value", "<b>This is new content.</b>");
      });

      btn1.onclick = function() {
          //  alert(editor.domNode.innerHTML);
      alert(editor.attr("value"));
      }

  });
```

Comment: You could probably answer your own question and set it to accepted answer, just in case someone (like me) have the same problem, and can't immediately see what the answer is.

Comment: I agree - "Never mind, I solved it" is very frustrating to read - please if you want to particpate in community sites - give as well as receive. How did you solve it?

Comment: Grouchal, he has the answer listed: editor.attr("value")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As marko has pointed out, you can get the value by:

```
editor.attr("value")
```